# Javascript funktion works only once on mobile webbrowser

Tags: javascript, html

I have on html site a button:

```
<input type="button" class="red" id="allClose" value="Close" onclick='change_pin ("1");'>
```

On click it call a java script funktion, that opens a php file, where are commands for Raspberry Pi to change given GPIO state.

```
 <script>
        function change_pin ( num ) {
        //send the num number to gpio.php for changes
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.open( "GET" , "gpio.php?num=" + num, true);
            request.send(null);
            return 0;
        };
    </script>
```

And it works fine on desktop browsers (Edge, Opera) but on desktop IE and Webbrowser on WP8.1 it works, but only once. When I press the button second time, nothing happen.  What I am doing wrong?